# "Python has stopped working" - when I am trying to display record from database to QListWidget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to display a list from database to the QListWidget according to QRadioButton toggled. I have used QButtonGroup for 4 QRadioButtons. I want a list of players related to the categories to be displayed on QListWidget which is fetched from database when QradioButton is checked. But when I click a QRadioButton it shows python has stopped working. Here is my code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect("fantcktdb.db")
cur=db.cursor()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.wkRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.wkRadio.setObjectName("wkRadio")
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)
        self.buttonGroup.setObjectName("buttonGroup")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.wkRadio)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.wkRadio)
        self.arRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.arRadio.setObjectName("arRadio")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.arRadio)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.arRadio)
        self.bowRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.bowRadio.setObjectName("bowRadio")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.bowRadio)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bowRadio)
        self.batRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.batRadio.setObjectName("batRadio")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.batRadio)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.batRadio)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonToggled.connect(self.showList)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.frame)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def showList(self,MainWindow):
        if (self.batRadio.isChecked()==True):
            cur.execute('''SELECT Player FROM stats WHERE Ctg='BAT';''')
            records=cur.fetchall()
            self.listWidget.clear()
            for row in records:
                self.listWidget.addItems(row)
            self.listWidget.update()
        elif (self.bowRadio.isChecked()==True):
            cur.execute('''SELECT Player FROM stats WHERE Ctg='BOW';''')
            records=cur.fetchall()
            self.listWidget.clear()
            for row in records:
                self.listWidget.addItems(row)
            self.listWidget.update()
        elif (self.arRadio.isChecked()==True):
            cur.execute('''SELECT Player FROM stats WHERE Ctg='AR';''')
            records=cur.fetchall()
            self.listWidget.clear()
            for row in records:
                self.listWidget.addItems(row)
            self.listWidget.update()
        elif (self.wkRadio.isChecked()==True):
            cur.execute('''SELECT Player FROM stats WHERE Ctg='WK';''')
            records=cur.fetchall()
            self.listWidget.clear()
            for row in records:
                self.listWidget.addItems(row)
            self.listWidget.update()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.wkRadio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WK"))
        self.arRadio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AR"))
        self.bowRadio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BOW"))
        self.batRadio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BAT"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have updated it. Is it enough?

Comment: I found that when I execute select query seprately in the code, it shows error like this.`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\FantasyCricket.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM stats WHERE Ctg="BAT";''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: stats`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not the issue with Qt but with database connection.
I encountered with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python36\Scripts\FantasyCricket.py", line 17, in <module>
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM stats WHERE Ctg="BAT";''') 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: stats
```

The solution is to give full path while connecting to the database like -
"C:\Python36\fantcktdb.db"